# Core data: get table and column information from object model

Tags: iphone, core-data

Is it possible to programmatically find out how core data matches a given class property to the database, i.e. in which table and which column the information will be stored?

Background: I would like to place an index on a specific column. I can find out the column by looking at the SQL core data executes. But there should be a more generic way to place the index, than hard-coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SQLite schema is a (private) implementation detail of CoreData. You can enable indexing of a property in the model editor in Xcode.